# How to specify the log using QRCoder to appear on the Google Authenticator

Tags: c#

I am using QRCoder that can be found [here](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/):

```
OneTimePassword generator = new OneTimePassword()
{
    Secret = "pwq6 5q55",
    Issuer = "Google",
    Label = "test@google.com",
};
string payload = generator.ToString();

QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(payload, 
QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
var qrCodeAsBitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20,Color.Black, Color.White, (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("logo-to-appear-in-QRCode"));
```

It all works as expected except that I can't see how I can specify the logo to appear beside my App's entry in Google Authenticator.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a file called "logo-to-appear-in-QRCode" (specially without the file extension)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman, thanks for the reply. That "logo-to-appear-in-QRCode" is only for the logo that appears in the middle of the QR Code. That is not my question. I am interested in the logo that appears on the Google Authenticator app after the user scans the code. Also that code is the minimal working code. You just have to add the package QRCoder and use qrCodeAsBitmap in an img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, doesn't seem possible with this library to achieve the desired change.

Comment: Correct, there's no logo parameter in the url format https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format